# C# script changes take 30+ seconds to import into Unity

Tags: c#, monodevelop, unity-game-engine

When I make a small script change in a C# script in MonoDevelop when working in Unity- even if all I do is add a space- the "Importing Assets" window appears when I return to the editor and takes between 30 seconds to a full minute to import that one tiny script change. Has anyone else had similar problems or does anyone know what could cause this?

Comment: Do you have a slower computer? It shouldn't take 30 seconds to recompile everything

Comment: Better question, how large is your script? It doesn't matter how big or small the change is, it still has to recompile the entire script.

Comment: It doesn't matter how big or small the script is. It happens with every script I save a change to, no matter how small or large.

Comment: I use a 2014 macbook pro, i7 2.8GHz

Comment: Which version of Unity are you using, and have you only noticed this slow down recently?

Comment: I'm using Unity 5.3.4p4. Yes, it has happened fairly recently, I'd say in the last couple months